# Show the Fibonacci numbers satisfy F(n) $\ge$ $2 ^ {(n-1) / 2}$

Tags: number-theory, induction, fibonacci-numbers

**Use induction to show that the Fibonacci numbers satisfy  F(n) $\ge$ $(2 ^ {(n-1) / 2})$ for all n $\ge$ 3**

My work thus far:

> Base Case: F(3) $\ge$ $2 ^ {(3-1) / 2}$ => F(3) $\ge$ $2 ^ {1}$
>
> Induction Hypothesis: Assume F(n) is true for all 3 < n < k
>
> Inductive step: for (k + 1), F(k + 1) $\ge$ $2 ^ {(k + 1 - 1) / 2}$ =>
>   F(3) $\ge$ $2 ^ {k / 2}$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how a proof by induction works. Say you have a proposition $P(n)$ to be verified for all natural numbers $n=0,1,2,\dots$. The **base case** is to show that $P(0)$ is true, which is usually the easiest. The **inductive hypothesis** is that for some $k$, $P(n)$ is true for all $n=0,1,2,\dots,k$. You seem to get the idea until now. The **inductive step** is to show, assuming $P(0),P(1),\dots,P(k)$, that $P(k+1)$ is also true. This is what allows the domino reaction to occur: once $P(k+1)$ is true, so is $P(k+2)$, and so on for every natural number.

In this case, $F(k+1)\geq2^{(k+1-1)/2}$ is what you **want to show**. You do not a priori know it to be true. Thus, it makes no sense to start by assuming it, as you seem to have done. Instead, start with the assumptions that
$$ F(k-1)\geq 2^{(k-2)/2}\quad\text{and}\quad F(k)\geq 2^{(k-1)/2}.$$
Note that by definition, $F(k+1)=F(k)+F(k-1)$. Summing the above two inequalities,
$$F(k+1)=F(k)+F(k-1)\geq 2^{(k-2)/2}+2^{(k-1)/2}.$$
The big question, now, is whether it is true that $2^{(k-2)/2}+2^{(k-1)/2}$ is greater than or equal to $2^{k/2}$. It turns out that it is true. To show this is the inductive step that you have to make and the conclusion that would complete the proof. Can you finish now?

---

Try completing the inductive step on your own first. If you need a hint, look below:

> Note that $2^{(k-1)/2}>2^{(k-2)/2}$, so $2^{(k-1)/2}+2^{(k-2)/2}>2\cdot2^{(k-2)/2}=2^{(k-2)/2+1}=2^{k/2}$.

Comment: Thank you @YiFan! This helped greatly. Just to make sure I understand completely, $2^{(−2)/2 + 1}$ becomes $2 ^ {k}$ which is greater than $2 ^{k/2}$ which leads to the conclusion?

Comment: @Ahan No, $2^{(k-2)/2+1}$ is $2^{(k-2+2)/2}=2^{k/2}$. Note that the exponent is $$\frac{k-2}{2}+1=\frac{k-2}{2}+\frac22=\frac{k-2+2}2=\frac{k}2.$$

Comment: Right, that makes more sense. I'm still failing to understand where the $2^k$ comes from though (at the end of the hint).

Comment: @Ahan sorry, that was a typo on my part. Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $F(n) \geq F(n-1)$ for all $n\geq 2.$ From inductive step we have that $F(n-1) \geq 2^{(n-2)/2}$.

Then observe that, for all $n\geq 3$

\begin{align*}F(n+1) & =F(n)+F(n-1) \\  
&\geq F(n-1)+F(n-1)\\
&= 2F(n-1)\\
&\geq 2 \times 2^{(n-2)/2} ~~~ \text{(from induction step)}\\
&=2^{n/2}
\end{align*}